# Strange CrystalReportsViewer toolbar behaviour

Tags: crystal-reports, windows-server-2008

I have a problem with the `CrystalReportsViewer's` toolbar that puzzles me. Let's say I have a report that consists of five pages.

- If I click the next button, I get to `page two` as expected, but if I press it again, `page two` reloads!
- I can click the `last page` button and get to the `last page`, but if I try to go to the previous page from there, I end up on `page one` again.

So, no matter how many pages my report has, I can only get to the first, the second and the last one!

These problems began when we migrated from `Windows Server 2003` to `2008`. We're running `Crystal Reports 10` which perhaps have problems under 2008? Can any of 2008's new security stuff be responsible for this?

Has anyone seen this behaviour before and know how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Rolling this back - it sounds like they are using the Crystal Report Viewer, which is a control that can be programmed...

Answer (score 1):

Never seen that Dev tool before so it won't be in our supported platforms.

I recall something similar and it was due to the screen resolution or zoom level.

Have a look at the source code of the page to see what it is doing. Compare it to a VS .NET ASP.NET app to see what the differences are.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this weird behavior before, but I know from a project I worked on a few months ago that Crystal Reports isn't supported on Win2k8 / IIS7 yet.  I wish I could find a link that stated that for you, but I remember running into that problem.

I had to go the route of setting up a virtual server to host Win2k3, just so I could publish some reports.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, it seems this isn't considered programming related (even though there's been a certain amount of programming to show the reports and that the CrystalReportViewer is a server control), so sorry about that.

Thanks Ken for your input. I bet i doesn't help that we're running an old version of CR as well. Maybe your route with the virtual 2003 machine is the best to go.